# How to reach the event when a <select> option is picked in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Can't believe I have to ask for this, but googling gave me nothing even though there are a couple of similar questions on here.

In the Meteor docs it says about the `change` event:

> A checkbox or radio button changes state. For text fields, use blur or
>   key events to respond to changes.

But what about a `select` box?

Here's mine:

```
<select name="item-list-in-select-box">
  <option value="empty"></option>
  {{#each items}}
    <option class="select-option-value" value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

How do I reach the event when someone chooses a value here? `change` doesn't work, neither does `click`.

**Edit:** As requested, the code I expected to work but didn't:

```
'change .select-option-value': function() {
  console.log("hey")
}
```

I've also tried `change select`, `change select.select-option-value`, `change [type=select]`, etc. etc. What is the right way?

Comment: HTML select elements emit a change event so there must be a problem with your event handler, you should edit your question to include its code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the scope of your event handler to use the name of the select element:

```
'change select[name="item-list-in-select-box"]': function() {
    console.log("hey")
}
```